# Adapter stuck to an old ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I am performing some reordering in a couple of array list, I have an adapter called

> adapterMeasureEvi

which is set to a static `ArrayList` called `measureEviArray` from `DataIpat` class.

When debugging I can see that the static list is been assigned properly and it follows a notification to the adapter that the list has changed.

```
DataIpat.measureEviArray =  (ArrayList<MeasureEvi>)measureEviArray.clone();
adapterMeasureEvi.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Problem is, when `getView()` method gets called the first item it brings is from the old list, when I look up into the objects their indexes have changed that means I have updated the attributes but why is it still stuck on the old list?

/////EDIT////

I just noticed on the constructor of the adapter class that the list is definitely the old one.

```
public MeasureTableAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<MeasureEvi> myMeasureEvi) {
    super(context, R.layout.adapter_tablamedida_item, myMeasureEvi);
    this.context = context;
    this.myMeasureEvi = myMeasureEvi;
}
```

this constructor is called just once when the object is instantiated, so I suppose it means it will be stuck there, how can I update that list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just stop cloning the list and work over the original worked, weird.

Deleted this,

```
DataIpat.measureEviArray =  (ArrayList<MeasureEvi>)measureEviArray.clone();
```

not ideal but a workaround

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when the data change, you recreate the `DataIpat.measureEviArray` instead of updating it. Hence your adapter will point to the old array, and the `DataIpat.measureEviArray` points to the newly upldated array. One way to fix your issue is instead of doing this (create a brand new array):

```
DataIpat.measureEviArray =  (ArrayList<MeasureEvi>)measureEviArray.clone();
```

You should just update the `DataIpad.measureEviArray` array so that this array contains your new data (e.g. using `clear` and `addAll` to basically get the same effect as creating a new `ArrayList`).